# Using Permanent Token in API HTTP Call

Tags: c#, webrequest, rest

I'm writing a C# desktop app that will make some API calls to retrieve some data in JSON in which I'll parse.  I'm using Deputy's API (https://www.deputy.com/api-doc/API/Getting_Started) and I'm having trouble getting it to work with a permanent token (I followed their steps and generated a token, so I have one).  In the past I usually just do a `HttpWebRequest` and pass it the api url and it works fine.  But in the past if there was an api key I would do something like `&api_key=api_key_here` or if I had an authorization key it would be something like `&Authorization=put_token_here`.

So I'm just trying to get Roster working for example:`/api/v1/supervise/roster/` (see https://www.deputy.com/api-doc/API/Roster_Management_Calls).

So my code looks something like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
            "https://mysite.na.deputy.com/api/v1/supervise/roster&Authorization=my_permanent_token_here"
            );
        httpWReq.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
        string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(responseString + Environment.NewLine);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(ex.ToString());
        });
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following:

> {"error":{"code":403,"message":"No authorization given"}}

I think it has to be the syntax on my permanent token, but I've tried `api_key=` and `token=` and `authorization=`.  Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the token as a line in the request header in the following format:

```
Authorization: OAuth YOURTOKEN
```

Use the following code:

```
string permanentAccessToken = "123456";

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://blabla");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + permanentAccessToken);
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  I used `"Bearer "` instead of `"OAuth "` for anyone else wondering.

Comment: I looked in this repository https://github.com/tonyallan/deputy/. And they use OAuth for the permanent token, so this should work as well.

Comment: Hmmm, I just tried with OAuth and it worked as well.  The only reason I used Bearer was because I've had a support ticket open with them and they kept telling me `Bearer<space><perm token>` but I was having trouble figuring out how to use that.  `request.Headers.Add` is what I needed.  Thanks